# Mobile Safari video question

Tags: iphone

I'm playing with the iPhone's Safari HTML5 `<video>` tag and I was wondering if there's a way to programmatically quit fullscreen mode once the video is done playing?

You start fullscreen mode using the play()-function, but how do you end it?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: I know, I was just trying to specify I'm talking about mobile safari :)

Comment: This article has a nice list of events you can listen for: http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/

Answer (score 4):

Use the "ended" event and the webkitExitFullScreen() method.

If you are using jQuery this is how you would do that:

```
// #video is the ID of the <video> element.    
$('#video').bind('ended', function() 
    {   
       var videoEl = document.getElementById('video');  
       videoEl.webkitExitFullScreen()

    });
```

The trick is sending video into fullscreen mode and playing the video all with one click on a thumbnail. For the life of me I can't figure that out!