# Can I play a youtube video in a UIWebView inline (not fullscreen)?

Tags: uiwebview, youtube, inline

I have looked everywhere on how to do this and haven't found an answer yet.
Is it possible to play a youtube video in a UIWebView on an iPhone inline, i.e. not fullscreen?
I know that the iPhone doesn't support flash, but youtube supports html5 and has h.264 videos doesn't it? shouldn't I be able to do this then?

I have set allowsInlineMediaPlayback to YES, but still it plays fullscreen.

Comment: try this one http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

Comment: u have to change frame size properties to achieve small

Comment: Thanks, but this example will play in fullscreen, not inline (tried it). The UIWebView's frame is already smaller than the whole screen, so the frame is not the issue here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to set property on UIWebView

```
 webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES;
```

And you need to add &playsinline=1 to YouTube iframe embedding code.

```
 <iframe webkit-playsinline width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GOiIxqcbzyM?feature=player_detailpage&playsinline=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Tested on iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.2 works like a charm.

Comment: This is correct-- with these two settings in place inline playback will work on iPhone.

Comment: can you please show the code with iFrame api of youtube? As i want to run the video from a certain time

Comment: Not sure what do you mean ? second line in the html (iFrame api).

Comment: If I understand correctly this requires an 'app' (i.e. access to UIWebView, which seems to be a browser type object) -- i.e. its not something I can leverage within a normal webpage. Is that correct? Is there a way to force iOS to play inline? (i.e. I have a video and want people to click a button when they see certain queues... a no-go if the vid plays full screen)...

Comment: Unfortunately your assumption is correct. This does not work in iPhone's Safari. You need to create you own app in witch you use UIWebView class. However it will work on iPad's Safari. You might be able to get it working on iPhone as well with custom html 5 player, but I never tried that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438520/html5-video-player-behavior-on-iphone-and-ipod-in-safari-web-apps

Comment: awesome solution +1...is it possible to play youtube video within its area, i dont want play in full screen.

Comment: Easiest Solution +1..Thanks

Comment: Does this work for ios8? I still got the video played full-screen.

Comment: I have a strange issue on iOS 9, it sometimes works, but mor often not

Answer (score 3):

**allowsInlineMediaPlayback UIWebView properties**

Boolean value that determines whether **HTML5** videos play inline or use the native full-screen controller. (developer.apple.com)

You can use this feature on iPad. On the iPhone there is no such function. If you try play video with uiwebview on iPhone it will be played in full screen mode.

Comment: That's not the case. -allowsInlineMediaPlayback will work on the iPhone, but you have to also include the webkit-playsinline attribute on the HTML video tag. See stringCode's answer.

Comment: @MarcCharbonneau Is this true for an iPhone on iOS 7?  Seems to force the fullscreen player

Comment: @matrosov , hello my friend, but i want to play video in UIWebview using HTML5 like vine app videos are being played.How can i achieve it in iPhone?

Comment: I also can't get this to work on iphone with ios 7.1. Did something change?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out on iPhone in iOS 8.x by chance?

Comment: @raphael I have not tested it on iOS8, I just tested it for previous versions many times ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can play any embed video inline UIWebView itself with help of "**playsinline=1**".

**Source code like:**

```
    NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1] ;
[html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
[html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[html appendString:@"body {"];
[html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
[html appendString:@"color: white;"];
[html appendString:@"}"];
[html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
[html appendString:@"<iframe webkit-playsinline width=\"300\" height=\"220\" src=\"http://www.ustream.tv/embed/23192315?html5ui&showtitle=false&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];
[self.webViewRef loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```