# Is there anyway to play a video inline in iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube, inline, playback

I've tried tens of different ways to play a video from YouTube or a server and not have it go into fullscreen. I know it's possible because the YouTube app allows for this to happen but can't seem to figure out how to do it. Please advise!

Comment: What are the methods you've tried?  Also... it seems only natural to me that `YouTube` will have more control over what `YouTube` videos will do in their own app then other users trying to tap into their videos...

Comment: If you know how to use flex, you could probably code a VideoDisplay object and change its properties and then embed it into an iframe, depending on how ios' markup is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:
[Can I play a youtube video in a UIWebView inline (not fullscreen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710461/can-i-play-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview-inline-not-fullscreen?rq=1)

This solution is iOS 6 & 7 compatible, it involves setting UIWebView's allowsInlinePlayback and setting YouTube's iFrame webkit-playsinline value.