# How to play Youtube Video from a browser app on non full screen in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-iframe-api, ytplayerview

I am working on Browser app, I want when user searches any video on youtube.com the video is playing on full screen but I want the video to be open on a fixed size small frame, Say Half of phone screen size.

I have Video url and video id. I have integrated YOUTube API but as soon as I hit play button on youtube player it plays on full screen.

Please find codebase of integration

```
self.playerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc]init];
self.playerView.frame = webView.frame;
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:str];

[webView.superview addSubview:self.playerView];
```

Please find the screenshots
[When youtube player is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyAeA.png) and [After tap on play button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H61R7.png)

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does you project have Controller named `MainViewController` , that controller should have issue with `YTPlayerView`, please check for this view in your view controller.
in most of the cases it will not defined in the class you have directly use in the code

---

Searching for the issue in your code i found a property of UIWebview which will help you in playing video inline `setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback`

With help of this you can directly play the youtube video in the webview, 
Here is code sample which you can use to play youtube video

```
 NSString *strVideoId = @"M7lc1UVf-VE";
 NSString *videoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?feature=player_detailpage&playsinline=1",strVideoId];

 NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html><head>\
                           <style type=\"text/css\">\
                           iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                           body {\
                           background-color: transparent;\
                           color: white;\
                           }\
                           </style>\
                           </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                           <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>\
                           </body></html>",videoURL];

[self.mainwebview setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:true];
[self.view addSubview:self.mainwebview];
[self.mainwebview loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

In this code you can pass any video id which you were passing in the `loadWithVideoId` of YTPlayerView 
To change the width/height you can make change in the `width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\"` portion of the iframe

It is working for me in the iPhone also which is looking like this:
[iframe youtube play in iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG0RI.png)
Another reference the `setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback` working in iPhone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15189889/4557505

The image which you shown in the screenshot looks like particular video issue
**Note** This code does not require `YTPlayerView` so if this code works for you, you can remove the `YTPlayerView` from your project if this is not used anywhere else

---

**Update** Some video not playing: 
I think this issue has not nothing to do with the specific implementation as for me it's not working in browser(with embed Url which we are setting in iFrame) or YTPlayerview also 
But till than i check and may be find some issue in implementation and as you have mentioned:

> Yes all videos worked on YTPlayerView. These videos work on normal
>   full screen mode but not with embedded player

If you want to make implementation in the YTPlayerview you can check the following code:

```
NSString *strVideoId = @"3bMYgo_S0Kc";
self.playerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc]init];
self.playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height/2);
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:strVideoId playerVars:@{@"playsinline":@1}];
[_mainwebview addSubview:self.playerView];
[self.mainwebview setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:true];
[self.view addSubview:self.mainwebview];
```

In the `loadWithVideoId` we can provide the inline parameter which can solve the problem of full screen and this may work for you on the iPhone also

**Note** this video is not working on YTPlayer or in browser(embedded url) for me but based on your comment you can try this

Comment: I have not added .a file in bundle, resolved this issue. Can you suggest if I play the video in a frame on iPhone using YTPlayerView?

Comment: When I tap on video button it plays on full screen

Comment: Please find the codebase I am using    self.playerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc]init];
  self.playerView.frame = webView.frame;
 [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:str];
  
  [webView.superview addSubview:self.playerView];

Comment: new comment added please check

Comment: I have checked with several videos, this issue is with not all videos, but setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback works only for ipad, it has no effect for iPhones/iPods

Comment: any idea how to resolve this video issue in [Last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36250287/5660422)

Comment: I think this is a video issue because few videos have this issue. Please suggest if you have any other solution.

Comment: no i didn't found any solution for that issue, for now you can use the iframe or the updated YTPlayerview with playerVars

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I appreciate this gestures of yours

Answer (score 1):

@Pyro

setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback works only for ipad, I have already enabled it. and it does now worked, It is not allowing to play the video.

[Image after implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiW6Z.png)

Comment: I don't think it's issue from the implementation side, does this video works with YTPlayerView and not working with iframe implementation?, please check on youtube if this has some permission/region specific issues

Comment: Yes all videos worked on YTPlayerView. These videos work on normal full screen mode but not with embedded player

Comment: ok, can you please provide me the video id so i can check from my side

Comment: _8aKKEjIO2g is one of them

Comment: ok , i will check if i found something but this video is even not playing in browser(https://www.youtube.com/embed/_8aKKEjIO2g) or YTPlayerView for me

Comment: 3bMYgo_S0Kc this is also one which is not working  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3bMYgo_S0Kc  converted url is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bMYgo_S0Kc&feature=player_embedded