# Html5 video tag inline at iPhone and iPad issue in iOS6

Tags: html, video, inline

Is that no way to do it?  I have a site want to build to using video for background, iPad runs perfect but iPhone's not.

Then I found out the problem is iPhone safari handle the inline html5 video by default full screen, some people said it could override by html5 settings with webkit-playsinline option, but I tried and no effect on the problem.

And I also found this link:
[HTML5 video player behavior on iPhone and iPod in Safari Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438520/html5-video-player-behavior-on-iphone-and-ipod-in-safari-web-apps)

The answer said the behivaor cannot be change even using the webkit-playsinline on it.

It that true?  And if yes, are there any way to do the inline video in iPhone?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that Apple doesn’t want webapps to succeed since they don’t pay 30% of the sales to them.

Answer (score 0):

With iPad you can disable inlineMediaPlaybackRequiresUserInput in Objective-C for a web view.

On iPhone, Apple doesn't allow this option at all, so your at a loss on iPhone.

A workaround is a bit old-school, but you could use an Animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by simulating the playback by *skimming* the video instead of actually `.play()`'ing it.

I wrote a module that takes care of playing the video and synchronizing it to the audio (but it also works on videos without a sound track): [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video)

Keep in mind that this still needs a "touch" to start, so it won't `autoplay` like on desktop.